# Run python3 as root in CentOS

Tags: python, linux, centos

I need to run a script with root privileges, but python3 has different behaviours:

In ubuntu I get:

```
/ubuntu/server$ sudo python3
[sudo] password for myuser: 
Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pathlib
>>> pathlib.Path.home()
PosixPath('/home/myuser')
```

While in CentOS is;

```
[centos@localhost ~]$ sudo python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug 24 2020, 17:57:11) 
[GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pathlib
>>> pathlib.Path.home()
PosixPath('/root')
```

How can I get the path of the user who did sudo python in Centos?

Comment: If nothing else works, `os.environ['SUDO_UID']` should give you their uid, which you can look up in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: HTF's answer is correct - but to be more explicit: the behaviour on your Ubuntu instance is the outlier;  `PosixPath('/root')` is the expected default.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying logic in the [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/pathlib.py#L373-L386) will try to check `HOME` variable to get the `homedir` on POSIX systems. You can either use `sudo -E python3` or `sudo --preserve-env=HOME python3` to preserve it.

**man sudo:**

> -E, --preserve-env
> Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables.  The security policy may return
> an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the
> environment.
>
> --preserve-env=list
> Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to add the comma-separated list of environment variables to those preserved from
> the user's environment.  The security policy may return an error if
> the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

Check if you have an alias set on your Ubuntu system, for instance:

```
$ alias sudo="sudo -E"
$ type -a sudo
sudo is aliased to `sudo -E'
sudo is /usr/bin/sudo
sudo is /bin/sudo
```